# Book - information page

Tags: book-design, front-matter, copyright

I have a question regarding the latex book class.

I want to add a page (in the frontmatter) with information regarding copyright, ISBN, edition information, publisher, number of copies, year of publication, place of print, etc.

Is there a standard way of getting this information printed nicely?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example, adapted from the [titlepages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages) source:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
%% copyrightpage
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\parindent 0pt
\parskip \baselineskip
\textcopyright{} 2013 Jubobs \\
All rights reserved.

    This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
of the Jubobs License.

    The Current Maintainer of this work is Jubobs.

    \lipsum[1-2]

\begin{center}
 99 32 11 88 48 01\hspace{2em}9 9 8 6 5 4 %1 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First edition:  & May 2013 \\
Second impression, with minor extensions & January 2009 \\
Third impression, with minor extensions & May 2013 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vfill

Bobs, Ju.\\
\hspace*{2em} Me, myself, and I / Jubobs. -- \\
\hspace*{1em} Toilet-paper Press ed. \\
\hspace*{2em} p. \hspace*{2em} cm. \\
\hspace*{2em} Includes illustrations, bibliographical references and index. \\
\hspace*{2em} ISBN \\
\hspace*{2em} 1. Book design \hspace*{2em} I. Title


\vfill

The Toilet Paper Press, \\
Portland, OR \\
\texttt{toiletpaper dot press (at) jubobs dot com}

%%%%{\LARGE\plogo}
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}


\endgroup
\clearpage
\end{document}
```